# Image delete security vulnerabilities

Tags: php, image-uploading, image-upload

I have developed a script to upload & delete images. The images will be saved to a directory like webroot/images. The file names relating to each users upload will be saved in the database when a publish button is clicked. Until then the images will be uploaded in order so that I can show a preview. All seems to work fine except a security vulnerability that allows users to delete other users images. Eg: Any user can copy the file name of an image & inject it to the delete script. Is there any mechanism to prevent this issue.

Hope this explanation isn't boring, its a little hard to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the database table that stores the image filenames, add a field for the `user_id` that owns the image.

When the delete action is invoked, lookup in the table to see if the current logged in user is associated with the image that they are trying to delete. If the `user_id` in the table doesn't match the logged in user then do not allow the delete.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The way I have developed the system is that the images just gets saved to a directory until all images are uploaded & the user clicks the publish button. Until then the images are just there in the webroot/images folder so that I can provide a live preview. If they are not happy they can unlink the image. And in this process I am not saving the image names relating to that user until he/she upload all the images. So I have no way of verifying who's image it is.

Comment: I guess this is the only way to allow this to happen (or at least the fastest one). For the purpose, you could add another table with just "ImageName" and "Owner" fields, and then follow MrCode's suggestion. Most likely you will have to change your code multiple times in the near future, so you should consider this advice.

Comment: How about storing it in the table but set a `published` flag to indicate if it's published yet. I don't see any way around using a table or at least some sort of data source to link users to images, even if they aren't published.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the file name of image before uploading. Timestamp is best in this case. For security concern, while deleting image you have to check the file is owned by current user or not.

Comment: I am changing the file name to a md5 hash. But after the images are published, it available to the public & anyone can see it. So, that allows them to see the image src which gives the file name.

Comment: That's the problem I have no way of checking whether the file is owned by the current user or not because I am not saving the file names of the images that are uploaded by individual users until a users uploads all his/her images & click on the publish button.

Comment: I encountered this before. You have to make a temporary directory. Upload initially in temporary directory and show the preview. If user click on publish, move images from temp to real directory.

Comment: Thanks. I am also created a temp_directory to upload the images. Sorry I didn't mention it my question. The users are also allowed to allow edit the images that are published. Which means I will have to move the images back to the temp_directory so that the preview won't be broken. And then the other users will find the images missing until the editing is complete. Hope this is clear enough. Appreciate your help, I'm struggling to fix this.